# Laravel multiple orWhere with and clause Eloquent

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

I used this code to fetch data in a search query. but didn't work the done_undone clause

```
                $members = DB::table('members')
                    ->where('name', 'like', '%' . $request->search . '%')
                    ->orWhere('contact_number', 'like', '%' . $request->search . '%')
                    ->orWhere('nid_number', 'like', '%' . $request->search . '%')
                    ->orWhere('nid_number', 'like', '%' . $request->search . '%')
                    ->where('done_undone', '=', 'undone')
                    ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
                    ->paginate(20);
```

Comment: Hi, did you try to write `where` like this: `$members = DB::table('members')->where([['name', 'like', '%' . $request->search . '%'], ['done_undone', '=', 'undone']])` ? Hope it helps.

Comment: Also, you've two `'nid_number'` lines. Think it's a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

There is a small mistake in your code with the sequence of where statement also you have duplicate statement in your code  pls. try below code:

```
$members = DB::table('members')
                    ->where('name', 'like', '%' . $request->search . '%')
                    ->where('done_undone', '=', 'undone')
                    ->orWhere('contact_number', 'like', '%' . $request->search . '%')
                    ->orWhere('nid_number', 'like', '%' . $request->search . '%')
                    ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
                    ->paginate(20);
```